# how to remove unwanted html flow chart line using css

Tags: html, css, nodes, flowchart

i have a flow chart done using HTML and css, I used the code from codepen to create the flow chart, the css is like below:

```css
.orgchart p {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: DarkTurquoise;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.orgchart p:hover {
  background-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.orgchart p .collapse {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: calc(50% - 6px);
  color: #EEEEEE;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}


/*chart nodes*/

.orgchart {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.orgchart,
.orgchart ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/*align children horizontally using CSS flex*/

.orgchart ul {
  display: flex;
}


/*align nodecontent and children list vertically*/

.orgchart li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}


/*arrange the nodecontent centered above the children list*/

.orgchart p {
  align-self: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 5px;
}

.orgchart .collapsed>ul {
  display: none;
}


/*connections*/

.orgchart li::before,
.orgchart p::after,
.orgchart p::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 0px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.orgchart li:not(:only-child)::before {
  border-top-width: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0px;
}

.orgchart li:first-child::before {
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  right: 0;
  border-left-width: 2px;
  border-top-left-radius: 7px;
}

.orgchart li:last-child::before {
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-top-right-radius: 7px;
}

.orgchart p::after,
.orgchart p::before {
  border-left-width: 2px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 20px;
  left: calc(50% - 1px);
}

.orgchart p::before {
  top: -20px;
}

.orgchart p::after {
  bottom: -20px;
}

.orgchart li:first-child:not(:only-child)>p::before,
.orgchart li:last-child:not(:only-child)>p::before {
  border-left-width: 0px;
}

.orgchart .leaf>p::after,
.orgchart .root>p::before,
.orgchart .collapsed>p::after {
  display: none;
}


/*vertical nodes*/

.orgchart li.vertical>ul {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 0 5px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.orgchart li.vertical>ul>li>p {
  margin: 20px 0 0 10px;
}


/*
ul.orgchart, .orgchart ul {
    border: 5px solid DarkBlue;
}

.orgchart li {
    border: 5px solid Lime;
}

.orgchart p {
    outline: 5px solid DeepPink;
}*/


/*vertical connectors*/

.orgchart li.vertical>ul::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  width: calc(50% - 19px);
  border-top: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.orgchart li.vertical>p::after {
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  width: 10px;
  left: auto;
  right: calc(50% - 1px);
}

.orgchart li.vertical>ul>li::before {
  border-width: 0 0 0 2px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.orgchart li.vertical>ul>li:first-child::before {
  top: -2px;
  height: calc(100% + 2px);
  border-top-width: 2px;
  border-top-left-radius: 7px;
}

.orgchart li.vertical>ul>li:last-child::before {
  height: calc(50% + 6px);
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
}

.orgchart li.vertical>ul>li>p::before {
  height: 2px;
  width: 8px;
  top: calc(50% - 1px);
  left: -8px;
  border-width: 2px 0 0 0;
}

.orgchart li.vertical>ul>li:last-child>p::before {
  display: none;
}

.vertical p {
  font-size: 7.5px !important;
}

.leaf p {
  font-size: 7.5px !important;
}

#toffymate a {
  color: white !important;
}
```

this is my full code: [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/o4kpe5wd/)

the problem is I am getting unwanted line in the flow chart like below which I have marked in yellow color:

[image]

can anyone please tell me how to remove it, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your chart with these css:

First, remove a line you don't need

```
.orgchart > li > ul > li:nth-child(4) > ul:before {content:none;}
```

Then move the line you need with the rounded corner pointing left so it's place over the top line

```
.orgchart > li > ul > li:nth-child(4):before {right: 116px;}
```

And finally change the vertical main line  so it won't show any top corner and stay in the right position

```
.orgchart > li > ul > li:nth-child(4) > ul > li:first-child:before {
    top: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top: 0;
  }
```

This is how it looks now: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dg2ts0ew/2/)

Comment: bro, i have another question regarding the same flow chart, if you could help me with that